# Is human mtDNA unique in its single origin?

Tags: genetics, mitochondria

Other than Humans, is there another primate who has a traceable “original Eve mtDNA”?

Comment: can you give some more background information on what your talking about? Can you define "original Eve mtDNA"?

Comment: I was referring to Prof. Sykes book the Seven Daughter of Eve referred to by another as Original Eve mtDNA!  My question was simple, is there a comparable circumstance in other primates?

Answer (score 3):

You can trace back any piece of DNA (from any life form) to a single ancestor called LUCA (Last Universal Common Ancestor), so the short answer is 'yes'. But be careful in your interpretation.

If you look backward in time, you can see that lineages merge (siblings merge first, then cousins merge, etc...) and you necessarily end up with a single individual. In absence of [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination) (which is the case for mtDNA), you can always trace back a piece of DNA this way and always find a single ancestor. The age of this common ancestor depends mainly on the population size and demographic history of the lineage. Typically, in a panmictic diploid population of constant size $N$, the expected time to the MRCA (Most Recent Common Ancestor) of the population is $2N$ generations.

So yes, you can find an "original Eve mtDNA" in any species. But please by "original" don't think this ancestor must have represented any novelty or anything of interest and do not make the mistake to think that before this ancestor no one had mtDNA.

The second paragraph is an extremely vulgarized explanation of coalescent theory. You should have a look at an intro to coalescent theory ([wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalescent_theory)) but you might well need an intro to evolutionary biology first. [Understanding Evolution](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) might be a good way to go.

Comment: Good answer. +1 Maybe, to further clarify things for the OP, one could add three things about what the 'original Eve mtDNA' carrier **was not**. (i) She was not **the only female alive at that time**. (ii) She was not **the ancestor of all genes in the gene pool**. (iii) She was not **necessarily a member of the species**.

Comment: Very important add-up to avoid misconception. Thank you

Comment: I was referring to Prof. Sykes book the Seven Daughter of Eve referred to by another as Original Eve mtDNA!  My question was simple, is there a comparable circumstance in other primates?

Comment: And I was thinking the answer was pretty easy as well. Please let us know what is unclear to you in my answer. Side note: please do not post the same comment twice.

Comment: Thanks, I am not academically trained.  What had confused me was that Prof. Sykes and others, currently seem to find this "Clan Mothers" evidence surprising.  However, if this is common in all life...my curiosity is satisfied.

Comment: I never heard of the concept of "Clan Mothers". If you want to question Sykes's claim you'll need to give more info about the concept he's using (give us some background) and probably quote him. You might need an intro level in evolutionary biology though before being able to do so (if you don't yet).

Comment: Sorry, I have asked my question poorly and confused it with the genealogy term. “The clan mothers were not the only people alive at the time, of course, but they were the only ones to have direct maternal descendants living right through to the present day. . They show how everyone alive on the planet today can trace their maternal ancestry back to just one woman.
Sykes wrote, and maps the migrations of the worlds populations  haplogroups.
My question is, how would this compare to chimpanzee populations?  Do all species inherently have an common core sequence in their mtDNA?

Comment: Well, yes this quote will be true for any piece of non-recombining DNA in any lineage (which includes mtDNA in chimps). The answer still hold. You should really read about coalescent theory to get a better understanding of this general subject.